# How to pass parameters to guizero event handler

Tags: python, user-interface, events, parameters

I'm trying to set up a GUI in Python with guizero but I am having trouble passing parameters to my key press handler. If I leave my function call empty, a default event_data parameter is filled with info on the event. If I try to pass my own parameter, it won't pass the event_data automatically. I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass my own parameter while also retaining the default event_data variable. Does anybody know how to set this up so I can pass my own parameter to my event handler while also keeping the event_data?

Here's the event documentation for guizero. They don't go over parameter passing, but it may be of help: https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/events/

I've tried passing default values or no values or the event_data itself but I couldn't get anything to work when filling in the parameter.

This works:

```
def keypress(data):
  if data.key == "\u001B":
    toggle_fullscreen()

app.when_key_pressed = keypress
```

But when I try to pass my own parameter:

```
def keypress(data, fullscreen):
  if data.key == "\u001B":
    toggle_fullscreen(fullscreen)

app.when_key_pressed = keypress(fullscreen)
```

It returns an error since only 1 argument is supplied out of the 2 required

UPDATE:

I tried setting up the function to accept both parameters and passed nothing to it:

```
def keypress(data, fullscreen):
  if data.key == "\u001B":
    toggle_fullscreen()

app.when_key_pressed = keypress
```

And I got the error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
*** GUIZERO WARNING ***
An event callback function must accept either 0 or 1 arguments.
The current callback has 2 arguments.
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does this mean I won't be able to pass any parameters to my event handlers?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use functools.partial(), for example:

```
import functools

def keypress(data, fullscreen):
  if data.key == "\u001B":
    toggle_fullscreen()

app.when_key_pressed = functools.partial(keypress, argument)
```

It does work on guizero event handlers, I actually had to do something very similar recently using functools.

Here's some more info on functools:
https://www.pythonpool.com/functools-partial/